# Alter one Table on Insertion into another

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, triggers

Let me first explain my situation here , I have a tabled called **users** which stores the user information.

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id  | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| username | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| password | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| name     | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| email    | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| status   | varchar(15) | NO   |     | active  |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And a table called **country**

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| country_id   | varchar(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| country_name | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| country_rate | double      | NO   |     | 0.2     |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Now , I need a process to map the no of countries assigned a particular user. 
For Example:

user_001 is allowed to use country_001 , country_002 , country_003 n

user_002 is allowed to use country_003 , country_008

and so on..

What is the best approach to achieve the above?

What I thought is to have a table called say assignment and it will have the following fields:

```
assignment_id (primary key)

user_id (foreign Key)

country_001 (bool)

country_002 (bool)

...
...

country_010 (bool)
```

I am not sure if this the best approach , but even if I go for this , I am stuck in the point as to how to alter the structure of assignment , on every insertion in the country table ( Add a BOOL field in assignment with the newly created country_id as the column name).

I hope I was able to explain m situation. I know I can achieve via language support code (PHP , C++ etc) , but I was thinking if this could be done using some kind of TRIGGER so that I don't have to care about it in the code section.

Thanks a Lot.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a better option to define `user_countries` table like this:

```
user_id fk on users(user_id)
country_id fk on countries(country_id)
unique key on ( user_id, country_id ) -- composite unique key
```

I am not sure why you want to define 10 columns in the user-country relation table.
But instead of 10 columns you just define a `country_id` with a foreign key and
with one-to-many relation ship between `user_id` and `country_id`. With this you can easily handle user and country relations. Unique key on their combination makes data access faster and avoids duplicates too.

Comment: So , what u are suggesting is to have one entry for each assignment? Like assign_001 , user_001 , con_002; then assign_002 , user_001 , con_004

Comment: Yes. And, `assignment_id`, I feel, is not that required. But I am not sure how you want to use it.

Comment: I think so, it would be better to have another table to handle users country